# How can I use HTML5 to add drag and drop functionality to my Google Chrome App?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, google-chrome-app

I'm attempting to add drag-and-drop to my chrome app.  Here is the code, but I can't get it to work.  Is there something I need to enable? Or am I not including something?  I'm simply trying to get something to work that places one div inside another.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>EOS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="open-player-position" class="open-position" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

    <div id="player1" class="collapsed-player" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
      <h4>Player 1</h4>
    </div>

  </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function allowDrop(ev)
      {
        ev.preventDefault();
      }

      function drag(ev)
      {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
      }

      function drop(ev)
      {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      }

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you must include your script code in javascript files, not inline, due to packaged apps [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy). This alone is likely the cause of your code not working.

Then, see examples of drag in drop in the samples. E.g. [Image Edit](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/image-edit) which uses the utility code from [dnd.js](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/image-edit/dnd.js).